# Power Automate flow for each user to consolidate data to one spreadsheet

Tags: excel, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I have a group of users, each of whom would have a copy of a Microsoft Form with attached Excel spreadsheet. I would love to have all of the data from each individual spreadsheet aggregated into a single Excel file that could be viewed by admin. My users would not have much experience at all customizing flows.

Is there a way to share a flow as a "template", which would allow each user to get their own copy?
In that flow template, I'd want to hard code the admin spreadsheet that data is being copied to, but allow them to select their own spreadsheet (once they've made a copy of the Form/Spreadsheet combo).

Comment: Have you stopped working with Googlesheets?

Comment: :) I know where you're going with this. We're an educational organization, and because of privacy issues, we have to use/switch to the Microsoft ecosystem instead of Google. I could easily build this in Google, but, you know, FERPA and laws and stuff.

Comment: My suggestion would be to have the workbooks emailed in to an automation user and that user will have the flow that does the work.  Therefore, no need to everyone to have a flow.  You could store the workbooks in SP or OneDrive and read each one (knowing who it came from because of the source email address) and then consolidate to a central workbook.

Comment: That's an intriguing idea that I had started to wonder about - but there is a little concern with users seeing other people's entries. Saving in a common SP might allow all SP members to see all data, yes?